# Rust long test names for BDD-style executable documentation

Tags: rust

I'm trying to find a way how to document my tests which might be rather long to fully explain the context and desired behavior(up to 10-12 words).

I'm more used to BDD style specs with nested contexts and verbose expectations but standard [test] attribute is fine as well.

**My question is:** can this happy-path snippet below be somehow rewritten for better readability?

```
#[test]
fn test_when_user_this_and_than_it_does_something_special() {
  // ...
}
```

I was looking for something like `#[test(name="plain text test case description")]`(to avoid heave snake_case naming) but without much success. Or perhaps there is a crate to mitigate this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rust does not have any kind of test *naming* separate from the function names. In order to include information about the purpose of the test, I would suggest that you write a concise name and documentation containing the rest of the words:

```rust
/// When the user does this and that, the special thing should happen.
#[test]
fn this_that_then_special() {
    // ...
}
```

You can also, if you want, put the comment inside the block using the inner doc-comment syntax `//!`:

```rust
#[test]
fn this_that_then_special() {
    //! When the user does this and that, the special thing should happen.

    // ...
}
```

Documentation for tests doesn't show up in generated documentation files, of course, so there isn't a whole lot of point to using the specific syntax, but it *is* a standard syntax for attaching an explanation to any item.